# Making my source code Read Only

Tags: javascript

Is is possible to make it so that when a user goes on my site and right clicks to view the source code, they are not actually able to edit it. I have it set so that the site broadcasts scores to a php database and I don't want users to be able to edit their scores.

Comment: No. Validate the score and user in PHP.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: I think we might need more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am making a sort of candy crush game, at the end of the allotted time the score is sent using AJAX

Comment: @JohnSmith If it's anything involving the security of your game, it *has to be done server-side* or people can do what they please with it. Client-side code is client-side for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to block the developer tools, you can block the rigth click and other things, but if the user wants to edit that, he will make a way to do it.
What you should do it's avoid to get this data from the front-end, if you show the user a score as example: 10

You need to get a way to get the same value on the backend, preventing the user to edit that data, otherwise the user will send anything that he wants to.

---

I've read your comment, and what you could make to dificult the user to hack the score, it's send it encripted, and on the backend you could decrypts it...
(But, this still doesn't solve your problem, as the logic of the encrypt data will be at the frontend, the user can check it and reverse the logic)